# Will static Stack<Activity> cause memory-leak？

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I create a object to manager the activities. like this:

```
public class ActivityManager {
    private static ActivityManager instance;
    private static Stack<Activity> activityStack;

    public void addActivity(Activity activity) {
        activityStack.add(activity);
    }
}
```

and I use it in the BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected String TAG = "BaseActivity";
    protected ActivityManager mActivityManger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActivityManger = ActivityManager.getInstance();
        mActivityManger.addActivity(this);

    }
}
```

in this example, the static object holding the reference of activity.

Is here a memory-leak?

Why nothing happened in leakcanary?

If the add-function in collection will hold a reference of activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try to leak something intentionally like assign your launcher activity instance to a static field.

Or try to press back, I believe this would trigger leak (and a toast would appear) after Activity was Destroyed and LeakCanary will detect if it leaked.

Or try to refer [here](https://anasmob.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-tutorial-use-leakcanary-to.html) for another sample

Comment: I know reference causes memory leaks. But in this example, nothing happened. If it is special for Collection?

Comment: I did not tried it before and is not on the documentation, but this could be another feature of the [this Repo][https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/README.md], I guess.

Comment: I have already used leakcanary. I feel puzzled if the add-function in collection will hold a reference of activity.

Comment: If you really wanted to check the Activity's instances try to line-break, and debug so you could easily analyze the List of Activity you added form there.